# Remove Orphaned Server from SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, server-farm, orphan

Looking for a supported method to remove **orphaned servers** from SharePoint 2013 Farm.

Initial process that led to current situation:

- Removed server from farm by using PSConfigGui

Upon navigation to **Production Sites**, server is still counted as a front-end for 3rd Party Licensing Purposes.

Still populated in Central Admin with **Distributed Cache** service still tagged on server.

Attempted to remove by clicking on `Remove Server`

Received Error:
`cachehostinfo is null`

Checking ULS Viewer revealed the following error
`A failure occurred SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance::UnprovisionInternal()... isGraceFulShutDown 'False' , isGraceFulShutDown, Exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: cacheHostInfo is null     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.Utilities.SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance.UnProvisionInternal(Boolean isGraceFulShutDown)'`

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean by "orphan". 
Does the server no longer exist? or 
The server thinks it is a member of a Farm that does not exist?

Comment: I actually ended up having to add quite a bit. Thanks dinos.kon. I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ps
$SPFarm = Get-SPFarm
$cacheClusterName = "SPDistributedCacheCluster_" + $SPFarm.Id.ToString()
$cacheClusterManager = [Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.Utilities.SPDistributedCacheClusterInfoManager]::Local
$cacheClusterInfo = $cacheClusterManager.GetSPDistributedCacheClusterInfo($cacheClusterName);
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.Service.Tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.Server.Name) -eq "ServerName"}
$serviceInstance.Delete()
```

Used search query:
`sharepoint remove server cachehostinfo is null`

Led me to the following Page:
[Habanero Consulting](https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2013/cachehostinfo-is-null-when-removing-a-server-from-a-sharepoint-2013-farm)

[StackExchange Reference with similar issue found here.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55076/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-cachehostinfo-null)

Answer (score -1):

For SharePoint 2013, Microsoft's article at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/remove-a-server-from-a-farm-in-sharepoint-2013) describes the process.

Comment: This is the initial process. My question regards the failure after this process.